# Passing Data to Intent / BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am calling an intent and the package is another app that I do not have control of. I have set up a BroadcastReceiver to listen and get a piece of data from the intent. This is working perfectly in the code I have attached.

My issue is I now need to do different actions based on data I would like to pass in from the activity calling the intent.

Is there a way to pass the data from my activity to the BroadcastReceiver that I can use? Any and all help is appreciated.

I have tried to use a bundle (putString and getString), but when the intent is started, it is the 3rd party intent and the only bundle is the data they are providing to me. The bundle I tried to pass does not exist.

call from MainActivity

```
        getTickets.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("Track", "MA1: " + Date().toString())
            if (checkOrientation()) {
                intent = Intent()
                intent.setAction("com.trakitgps.GET_VEHICLE_NUM")
                intent.setPackage("com.trakitgps")
                val filter = IntentFilter("com.trakitgps.GET_VEHICLE_NUM_RESPONSE")
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
class TrackItReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {


        when (intent.action) {
            "com.trakitgps.GET_VEHICLE_NUM_RESPONSE" -> {
                val truckNbr = intent.extras.getString("vehicleNum")
                val errorMsg = intent.extras.getString("errorMsg")

                val newIntent = Intent(context, TruckTicketsActivity::class.java)
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                newIntent.putExtra("assignedTruck", truckNbr)
                newIntent.putExtra("truckError", errorMsg)
                context.startActivity(newIntent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

When you create the `BroadcastReceiver`, pass it the data it will need in the constructor. Then, when`onReceive()` is called, it has the data that it needs. Something like this:

```
// Create the BroadcastReceiver
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver(data, another, andAnother);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
startActivity(intent)
```

In `MyReceiver`, declare member variables to hold `data`, `another` and `andAnother` and initialize them in the constructor.